# Cloudfront Caching based on Response Header

Tags: caching, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I have a problem with Paywall-Subscription. I want to cache free content in cloudfront, but do not cache any paid content, because we need to check the authorization token.

Let's say I have URL like

example.com/story/100 --> payed article, so authorization token must be checked, not cacheable, resonse-header is "Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-cache", answer is content (if correct token) or redirect to login page

example.com/story/101 --> free article, cacheable, response-header is "Cache-Control: max-age=3600"

This is not working because of the collapsed forwarding problem: concurrent requests are waiting for the first answer, so a user with a valid authorization token can still get the redirect to the login page.

If we had different URL's like "/story/" and "/freestory/" that would be easy to configure, but while we don't have that, I don't see a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what do you actually want to cache based on?

Comment: I want to cache based on max-age header and be sure that every request with max-age= 0 and/or private is delivered only to the requesting client. Varnish has something called "Hit-For-Pas" for this, but I don't find anything similar in Cloudfront.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RequestAndResponseBehaviorCustomOrigin.html#request-custom-traffic-spikes) says: "If additional requests are not identical because, for example, you configured CloudFront to cache based on request headers or cookies, CloudFront forwards all of the unique requests to your origin."  So it looks like you need to tell CloudFront to Vary based on your authorization header.

Comment: Yes. But vary on authorization header means no caching at all, except if the same user requests the same content again. This is perfect for the paid content case. But not for the free content. That should be cached for all users.